# Why does Typescript infer type of a value retrieved by absent key without undefined?

Tags: typescript, undefined, type-inference

I have this example code:

```
const example: { [key: string]: string } = { a: 'abc' }

const b = example['b']
```

At runtime, `b` would obviously be equal `undefined`, but at compile type, Typescript infers `b` type to be just `string` and not `string|undefined`. This seems like an error to me.

Why doesn't it infer it as `string|undefined`, and how can I force it to do so?

Comment: You've not specified that `example` can contain `undefined`. Either do `{ [key: string]: string | undefined }` or probably `{ [key: string]?: string }`

Comment: @VLAZ With the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag you can get typescript to automatically add `| undefined` on index lookup.

Comment: @Aplet123 ah, useful to know! It's a new property it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You broaden the type by casting it to `{[key: string]: string}`, so from a type perspective, `'b'` is as valid a key as `'a'`. Omit the type and let typescript infer a narrower type, and an error will be thrown:

```js
const example = { a: 'abc' };

// error: property 'b' does not exist
const b = example['b'];
```

There's a discussion about adding `| undefined` to index lookups on [GitHub issue #9235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9235), and it was actually resolved with a `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag [added in typescript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access). If it's set, then `b` will be `string | undefined`, even in your example.

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAuGBvAbQGs4BPXaAJwEswBzAXQqhvoF8YBefGJXAciQAjYPxhsA3ACgpAelkwoAC2oQYAd2oYMMIXBhVadGAB8YAVzAATOADNacK1NCRYQrvGTosBfkP4M0nIKyqoaWjpIGBAguvqG9KYW1nYOVjBW5vpQsaQg5rqUIEg2YEaKStmkaHDO4NC8HoiomHC+SAESQA)

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error. Considering typing only : `'b'` could be a valid key.

The type `{ [key: string]: string }` specifycally tells Typescript that `example` can contains any key name.

Typescript is not *analyzing* your variable. It only compare type and see if they match.

---

In the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90DMB7QtAbgChyBjQgOwWCggA8MBbMAGwgC4oBvKAG04IKAEtaseAgC6Afj4MATpIDmUAL4oBUDH0wAjKtk2Ua9RoZ0t2XCELSG0soA) typescript show you an error. Because you list the keys that can exists or not.

```
type keys = 'a' | 'foo';

const example: { [key in keys]?: string } = { a: 'abc' }

const b = example['b']
```

---

[image]

Comment: "'b' could be a valid key" — that's true, but it's just "could be". It does not provide a guarantee that it's valid, unlike a type with explicit not-optional keys.

Comment: With the type `{ [key: string]: string }`, typescript consider that every key exists. It will never show you an error. It's how it works.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT is correct. The compiler does what you told it to, not what you want it to.

Comment: Your example still doesn't allow arbitrary keys. I want to tell the compiler that I don't know what keys will be present or absent in the object, just that they will be strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting example to be of `{ [key: string]: string }` type. In other words, you are telling typescript it is always a string. There is no way of typescript analysing if it is really on there or not as its a statically typed language.